# WSO2 API Manager Car

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

Why can't I upload the API Analytics car into the API Manager admin?

There is a warning that says :

```
Undeploying Faulty Carbon Application On : C:\WSO2AM~1.0\bin\..\repository\deployment\server\carbonapps\API_Manager_Analytics.car {org.wso2.carbon.application.deployer.CappAxis2Deployer}
TID: [-1234] [] [2016-09-23 14:36:10,436]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.application.deployer.internal.ApplicationManager} -  Deploying Carbon Application : API_Manager_Analytics.car... {org.wso2.carbon.application.deployer.internal.ApplicationManager}
TID: [-1234] [] [2016-09-23 14:36:10,618]  WARN {org.wso2.carbon.application.deployer.internal.ApplicationManager} -  No artifacts found to be deployed in this server. Ignoring Carbon Application : API_Manager_Analytics.car {org.wso2.carbon.application.deployer.internal.ApplicationManager}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, Analytics car files should be installed in DAS, not in APIM.

If you want to install any (other) car file in APIM, make sure you set Server Role as Api Manager in each artifact in the car.